# What is this song title and band name?

Tags: traducción

In listening to Spanish radio lately, I really love some of the music played, such as "El Amor de su Vida" (easy enough to understand), and "Te Metiste"

But what does the title mean? And the name of the band?

*Te Metiste* - google translate says, "you got" ... ???

*Plebes del Rancho* - google translate fails ignominiously/in epic proportions. Is it something like "ranchhands"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Te metiste" means "you got into", as getting into trouble, or getting into some place. As a slang it could also mean that you inserted something into your body (food, drink, drugs...). Figuratively it could also mean many different things:

*Te metiste en problemas* → *You got into trouble*

*Te metiste en el bar* → *You entered the bar*

*Te metiste un filete* → *You ate a steak*

In this particular case, "Te metiste" means "You entered":

*Te metiste completamente en mi vida* → "You entered completely in my life". Notice that in other contexts, "meterse en la vida de alguien" would mean "to meddle in the life of someone"

The name *Plebes del Rancho* means, in mexican (because it's a mexican band, in other countries it would have a [slightly different meaning](http://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Plebe.php)), *Ranch boys*, with "plebe" meaning that, boy, or cubbish/disrepectful boy. Its root is the same as "plebs".